# Why is Stack Overflow not working?

Tags: support, 500-server-error

Why is Stack Overflow not working? All I get is this [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.
```

[image: Screenshot of]

Thanks to some comments below, these two tweets from the *[StackExchange Status](https://twitter.com/StackStatus)* [sic] account describe the problem so far:

- https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/395563402812063744
- https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/395567642162896898
- https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/395588967426306049

Comment: Yes, it's __not__ working.

Comment: Because someone broke it :-p wait 1min and it should work

Comment: It's working again! :D

Comment: Oscillation, my dear Jake

Comment: Oh, it is.. Wait.. It's not.

Comment: @HugoDozois wait several minutes...

Comment: Oscillation, my dear @devnull

Comment: [Let's see whose fault it is](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/)

Comment: It is still down.

Comment: https://twitter.com/tinkertim/status/395560348951916544

Comment: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/395563402812063744

Comment: @AndrewBarber I like this better: https://twitter.com/H2CO3_iOS/status/395561379593076737

Comment: I like refreshing on SO just to see all the different WORKIN ON UR PROBLEMZ pictures... jeez, how many are there?  I'm probably generating an error report each time :P

Comment: Still is down for me... Not sure why this is on hold as "can no longer be reproduced".

Comment: @LBT My bet is you are making the problem worse. hehe

Comment: @MartinSmith Nice link. :)

Comment: Why would someone favorite this question? o_O

Comment: @Ricardo so that we know when SO is back up, duh

Comment: @Dave F5 and you can still know, duh lol

Comment: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/395567642162896898

Comment: My veins are itching and those yummy questions are my only fix!

Comment: I've not been able to answer a question for FORTY MINUTES. This is critical! Just send over database details and I'll SQL insert my answers. I have so much work to avoid and no reason to avoid it!!

Comment: @Damien I have it all in a directory of Excel files if that helps.

Comment: @JakeBraun If you can then import that into the database when we're back up I'll get cracking ;)

Comment: @Damien I can only export to CSV.

Comment: @JakeBraun send them over. I have the all answers, I promise, I'm good for it.

Comment: I observe that the https://www.stackstatus.net/ site is stuck in a time warp.  The second entry says "**stackexchange.com outage - 2010-10-10**
We are continuing to investigate an issue with stackexchange.com site degradation.  At the moment, we are not displaying favicons for the sites while we diagnose the issue further." but is marked as being posted '2 weeks ago'.  I believe the 2010 should be 2013.  And, FWIW, the favicons are still not being displayed, if I'm to believe what I see with Chrome (30.0.1599.101 on Mac OS X 10.9).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler https://www.stackstatus.net/ is not updated, out of date and honestly, the last place I would check. Twitter is the place, I start with the [official twitter](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) then jump to Nick's, Marc's and maybe more dev's twits.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My favorite - made my day:

> An error has occured while creating an error report.

[image]

Comment: Simple solution...create error reports for error reports.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

---

[image]

[link to the status blog](https://www.stackstatus.net/)